# Which social connect plugin do you recommend?

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm searching a social connect plugin which allows users to register/login using the following sites and support MULTISITE
1)Facebook
2)Twitter
3)Google
4)Yahoo 
5)Others (optional)

I've tried many plugin but none of them met my requirements.
Plugins that support facebook,twitter,google,yahoo has security issues.

I've tried otto's simple facebook and twitter connect. It is a good plugin but it doesn't support multisite, also there is no yahoo connect.

[Social connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/) has everything,support multisite, but its not working properly. Many times its not redirect to the dashboard after connect.

I tried [wordpress social login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/) plugin too. But after connect its just fill dummy emails for everything even you connect with google,yahoo,etc.

I don't want to use third party plugins like janrain,gigya etc... Because after some limit i need to pay money to use their services.

Is there any good plugin available that support multisite and has high security,facebook,twitter,google,yahoo connect features ?

Thanks

Comment: SFC and STC both support multisite just fine. I use them on multisite systems myself. STC does not have registration capabilities though.

Comment: Oh thats cool. But i found another problem here. New users cannot able to signup with twitter. They should manually register first and then connect twitter from their profile to use it. Is there a way to override this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This plugin should suit your needs!
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/oa-social-login/

Comment: Why? An answer should be [more than a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).

Comment: why not, as long as its helpful it should be ok

Answer (score -1):

I am co-founder of LoginRadius and our plugin ['Social login for WordPress'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/) enables login via popular ID providers such as Facebook, Twitter, Google and over 15 more. You can download and try it [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/).

We also support multiple sites from single account.

Following are primary features of this plugin:

- Social login
- Select desired ID providers you want your users to log in with
- Get User profile data and save them in your database as well auto-fill various forms
- No programming skills required
- 24x7 email support